# xfce Window Border Mouse Hover Transparency

Tags: window, themes, xfce, gtk

I've recently started using Linux and I'm enjoying customizing the DE to how I like it. One thing I'd love to be able to do is have the window border of applications (where the program title and close button are, I think it might be called the window decoration but I'm not sure) to be fully transparent until my mouse hovers over it and makes it visible.

I've tried to mess around with a lot of the theme files like gtkrc and themerc but haven't been able to get anything to work. I don't really understand the options in the gtkrc files like main.rc or panel.rc, or where the window borders would even be controlled among these files, and in themerc which directly controls the window borders the 'code' is a different format to the other files. I'm using Arc-Dark and Fedora 27, just to give all the information.

If anyone knows how to do this, if it's at all possible, I'd appreciate some help.